# Push a branch into a newly created Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-subtree

I'm currently switching over to using mono repos, since it fits my workflow better. However, I still want to be able to deploy/use parts of the now huge project separately. That is why I came across splitsh-lite (https://github.com/splitsh/lite), a replacement for `git subtree`.

So, my project structure of the main (mono) repository is as follows:

`/
-- some-application/
-- src/
-- -- MyLibrary1/
-- -- MyLibrary2/`

*mono repo master*

Using splitsh-lite, I've managed to extract the contents of the repository that I want to split into an own branch. Let's say I've split MyLibrary1:

`/
-- file1
-- file2`

*mono repo split/library1*

What I didn't manage to do now is getting this newly created branch into the master branch of a fresh repository on Bitbucket (or actually any Git repository). I've mainly tried two variations that seemed logical to me.

1. `git push git@bitbucket.org:my-project/my-repo split/library1:master`, resulting in `error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master
   The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
   begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.`
2. Pushing it to an empty local repository (`git push ../library1 split/library1:master` resulting in the same error

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to continue from here, because I don't really how to go on from here. :(

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the above commands should be working as intended. The issue however is, that Git is somehow not able to resolve "master" into an actual reference. The problem is solved by specifying the exact reference:

`git push some-repo-path split/library1:refs/heads/master`

Me and some guy from #git (freenode, thanks for helping, again!) couldn't figure out why Git couldn't do it, though, which is a little unsatisfying.

Answer (score 0):

In the main repo directory, there is a hidden directory called .git

Within it there's a file called config. You should add there the new remote repos...

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Adding the new repository as remote and referencing it instead of putting the Repo URL directly doesn't change anything unfortunately.